# Angular-7 active link on tab is not working?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, mean-stack

I have **4 icons** on which i'm trying for **active link** like this -[![like yellow active tab][1]][1] but it's not working don't know why i guess i'm missing some steps also when i'm **changing router** i need to **highlight** that router tab.
Here is my **.Html file** for one module -( i only made changes in .html not .ts file)

```
 <div class="smart-manage">
 <a routerLink="/dashboard" class = "active" routerLinkActive = "active"[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" >
              <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Smart Dashboard" data-placement="right">
               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0
                                20 20" width="20" height="20">
```

Comment: Remove active class

Comment: Can you create a minimal stackblitz ?

Comment: project is really big i can give you link also i'm working in http://localhost:4200/home

Comment: How anyone would be able to access your 'localhost' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your code:

```
 <a routerLink="/dashboard" class="active" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
```

When the url is '/dashboard', the active class will be added to the a tag. If the url changes, the class will be removed.

Problem: You add the class anyway with `class="active"`

Try:

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
```

With styles:

```
.active { color: red; }
```

The a tag text will be red on active.

Comment: Thank you but i did try your method and it's not working @angular :(

Comment: It should work. May You provide a sample reproduction with stackblitz ?

Comment: i am working on localhost and my  address is http://localhost:4200/home

Comment: You removed class="active" and while you navigate on /dashboard the class isn't added ? What is the exact url when you navigate on dashboard ?

Comment: Update your origin post and show me complete html + css

Comment: Thank you so much it works there is small issue in my .css file